# Tomcat Basic Authentication for 1 Webapp only

Tags: authentication, tomcat, web-applications, basic-authentication, tomcat8

I have Apache `Tomcat8` running on a windows server and have multiple `webapps` deployed inside it.

I am trying to add basic auth to just 1 `webapp`, so users can continue to use the other apps without having to authenticate against `Tomcat`, but they will need to authenticate against `Tomcat` just for this one application.

Is anyone able to help me out here? I'm somewhat of a newbie when it comes to `Tomcat` config!

The following configuration works, however, this enforces basic `auth` on all `webapps`, not just the one I want.

web.xml updates:

```
  <security-role>
    <role-name>role1</role-name>
  </security-role>
  <security-constraint>
      <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </web-resource-collection>
      <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>role1</role-name>
      </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
  </login-config>
```

In tomcat-users.xml a single user is configured with role="role1"

I have tried to change the url-pattern to the following:

```
<url-pattern>/my-account/*</url-pattern>
```

However, `Tomcat` now doesn't ask for authentication at all here. Basic `auth` is disabled and no applications require authentication.